# How to disable screen lock sound in android app?

Tags: android-audiomanager, android

I have one android application so

1. my application is running foreground
2. and I click power button
3. Beep sound comes
4. my phone goes into sleep
5. When i again click power button
6. my phone wake up
7. I unlock my phone
8. again Beep sound comes
9. screen goes to my application screen

Here i do not want that beep in case 3 and case 8 so how can i do that from my application code?

**Edit:** 
I know this can be done by from setting->sound->screen lock sound checkbox but i need to do this just for my app only no matter whats general setting for screen lock sound is selected.

Comment: i think this will annoy user

Comment: You should not setup your post like this, post a sentence instead of steps.. to your problem.. which contextually makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put below code in your android app where you want to turn off the screen lock sound.

If you using Activity use below code :

```
Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), "lockscreen_sounds_enabled",
                            0);
```

If you using Fragment use below code :

```
Settings.System.putInt(getActivity(),getContentResolver(), "lockscreen_sounds_enabled",
                            0);
```

To enable it again you can set 1 instead of 0.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This isn't something you need to program - this setting is in Android settings, sound settings, "Screen lock sounds". Since that's an option for the settings app, I doubt you can change it from your app. (Changing other applications' data is forbidden unless it's root/system app)

Comment: there is not something you overwrite that sound effect on power button for your application's activity?

Comment: Looks like I may be wrong - see the other answer. (I didn't know there was an api for that). Why would you want inconsistent behavior, only in your app though?